# How to write clusters to file more efficiently?

Tags: python, data-mining

this is kind of a dumb question but basically I have my data divided into different clusters using k-means, this is for a class project btw. I have everything working but I have to write my clusters into a file for each input so that it can be tested. My actual code takes about 2-3 mins to run but it takes like 10 mins for it to write to file. I have 10,000 inputs/outputs and currently my runtime is around n^3. The time doesn't really matter as far as the assignment is concerned but I wanted to know if someone can help me optimize it, I know there's different Python iteration tricks that I am not aware of which could speed this up.

My k is 10 so I have 10 centroids, basically I pick array and pick one of the centroid, check if it has the array in it, if it doesn't, I move to the next one and so forth. I do this for each 10,000 input which takes a long time. The code isn't very efficient

```
file = open("image.txt", "w")
    for point in array:
        for x in range(len(centroids)):
            for i in centroids[x]:
                if np.array_equal(point,i):
                    file.write(str(x+1)+"\n")
    file.close()
```

Comment: You probably need a mix of `numpy.intersect1d` (this could be used to find row-wise intersection of 2D arrays too) and `numpy.savetxt`... Do you try to find intersection between `array` and `centroids` and write the result to a file?

Comment: If your centroids is a list then `for ct in centroids` instead would save you one level of nesting. I would also prefer to perform the intersect operation outside of the file buffer actually.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me try to clean some stuff up. Comment and let me know if anything I say is not applicable. Also, if you have to check everything then you might not be able to simplify the calculations.

```py
with open("image.txt", "w") as file:
   for point in array:
      for centroid_index, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
         for centroid_point in centroid:
            if np.array_equal(point,centroid_point):
               file.write(str(centroid_index+1)+"\n")
```

If you could explain the object types of `array`, `centroids`, and what you are trying to write to the file for me, then I could give some more specific methods.

Comment: array is a numpy array that holds all my data, size is 10,000 x 749
Centroids are my clusters, there are 10 of them. Each cluster then holds different arrays that represent my points. So basically I have to check each cluster and then check each point in that cluster to see if any of it matches my current point

Comment: Okay so I actually just created an array and added the cluster value to each index when I assigned points to the cluster. That way, I only have to go and write the array values to file!

Comment: You should still use the context manager and syntax I showed. Its cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

This line is a bad idea:

```
for point in array:
```

*Why* iterate over the points to find the centroids?

Just output them by index, and iterate only over the centroids.